# ROS + Raspberry Pi + Motor Shield

Tags: ros, python, raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there

I am currently learning ROS and have a BrickPi motor shield which I would like to control in ROS

Are there any good tutorials for controlling a Raspberry Pi Python based motor shield?

I am guessing I need to write a subscriber in Python?  Most of the Arduino examples I see use serial.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250942/ros-+-raspberry-pi-+-motor-shield/) by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2016-12-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

some years agi I tried the BrickPI+RPI for LEGO equipment (motors and sensors).

Check this for a start:
https://github.com/mockbot/MockBot/blob/master/mockbot/bin/brickpi.py

Good luck
Christian

---

Originally posted by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) with karma: 476 on 2016-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2016-12-30**:
Thank you, that looks epic.  Did you do a model for it to? so you can use it in RVIZ?

**Comment by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) on 2016-12-30**:
No, I've never did it.
A small picture only :-)
https://x49svr40x172.xdsnet.de/xCloud/index.php/s/DezKU5xeir0WtVj

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2016-12-30**:
Thank you, I want to be able to use path finding with something I am building https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ojPM1XSDD9M I guess, I need to use your script, then model the robot then use rviz to control it

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2016-12-30**:
Do you have any tele-op control for your script?

**Comment by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) on 2017-01-01**:
Sure:
I using this small web-teleop for all my gadgets :-)

https://github.com/mockbot/MockBot/blob/master/mockbot/html/mockbot/mockbot-teleop.html
(rosbridge must be started at you robot before)
Nice tool for remote teleop and first person camera view :-)

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-01-03**:
Whats Rosbridge for?  I go and google it :) So when I mean teleop, I mean a way to control the robot via the keyboard etc

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-01-04**:
Just tried your script, you rock mate, super useful!

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-01-10**:
Did you do any encoder examples mate?